# sphinx cuts symbol

Tags: search, filtering, sphinx

I have a music collection and use sphinx for searching in it. Search mode is SPH_MATCH_PHRASE, but when I search f.e. for "B'Day" album - sphinx cuts "'" and searching by "Day" query. How can I force sphinx to search by exact phrase without filtering any symbols?

Comment: Sphinx splits query "B'Day" into 2 words:

sphinx-search "B'Day"
Sphinx 0.9.8.1-release (r1533)
Copyright (c) 2001-2008, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
index 'artistsIndex': query 'B'Day ': returned 0 matches of 0 total in 0.000 sec

words:
1. 'b': 132 documents, 143 hits
2. 'day': 62 documents, 62 hits

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that char ' is treated by sphinx as a word character.

In order to do this, you need to specify the list of word characters in charset_table

For example:

```
# treats all english characters and ' as word characters 
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z,'
```

After that you'll need to rebuild the index and restart searchd.

See http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

Answer (score 0):

I set param min_word_len = 1 in index config and it works well!